# Multiple dot in element Id a No no?

Tags: jquery

**Edit**

Thank you for all the comment and answer.I am baffled, I am able to fix the problem after trying out the different answers, but now is not able to reproduce the problem ??? I don''t know what happened.

What I am trying to do is get an element by id, but this id contains multiple dots in it because the id is the "path" from in an XML doc. So I assume that if you have multiple dot in the id name even though you have escaped them it will not work?

```
var triggerElementID = "a.b.c.d";
var eleId = triggerElementID.replace(/\./g, "\\\\.");
console.log(eleId);
var thisele = $('#' + eleId);
console.log(thisele);
```

The above code is what I have it it does escape the the dot, console.log prints out this `a\\.b\\.c\\.d` while the console.log of `thisele` prints out this

```
[prevObject: b.fn.b.init[1], context: document, selector: "#a.b.c.d", jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function…]
context: document
length: 0
prevObject: b.fn.b.init[1]
selector: ""#a.b.c.d"
__proto__: Object[0]
```

Comment: You should change the dots in the `"path" from in an XML doc` to something more sensible, like hyphen or underscore.

Comment: Can you set up the 'id's with, say, underscore in them instead of a dot and then replace the dots with underscores before doing the selector?

Comment: it will work see [example](http://jsfiddle.net/3yAGc/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when i encountered this problem i was able to use this:

```
$("[id='" + eleId +"']");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tmw63/

Answer (score 1):

jQuery uses the [sizzle.js](http://sizzlejs.com/) CSS3 selector engine. Which will translate them to `a.b.c.d` to a chained selector, where `.` takes on it's traditional meaning of a class. So it would be equivelant of:

```
a with [a class of] b [and a class of] c [and a class of] d
```

Now sizzle, and therefore jQuery, does mean that escaped selectors are supported (See [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)) but should be escaped with two backslashes. (`\\`)

It would appear that there may be an issue with your regex if jQuery is still saying the selector is `a.b.c.d` despite trying escape them.

```
-> var triggerElementID = "a.b.c.d";
-> var eleId = triggerElementID;//.replace(/\./g, "\\\\.");
undefined
-> eleId
"a.b.c.d"
```

Testing it in a developer console supports this theory too.

***Edit: Didn't see that the .replace() call was commented out in your above code. Works correctly when uncommented...***

Answer (score 0):

You have too many slashes in your replacement string.

```
var triggerElementID = "a.b.c.d";
var eleId = triggerElementID.replace(/\./g, "\\.");
var thisele = $("#"+eleId);
console.log(thisele);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/8cVYH/4/)

Comment: ```->"a.b.c.d".replace(/\./g, "\\\\.");```
```"a\\.b\\.c\\.d"```
```-> "a.b.c.d".replace(/\./g, "\\.");```
```"a\.b\.c\.d"```

They need to be escaped with TWO slashes, requiring an additional slash to escape the slash itself. Whilst it does work, it's undocumented behaviour and they should really be escaped with two. +1d because it works anyway, I was too hasty ;)

Comment: That's what the OP tried, which didn't work. You only need double slashes in string literals, jQuery only needs one slash in the actual string.

Comment: @melc - see my comment, it's [undocumented behaviour](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and reallllyyy shouldn't be relied upon.

Comment: I think that documentation is describing how to type the selectors with special characters literally. You have to type `$("#a\\.b\\.c\\d")`, because Javascript removes one of the slashes when it's parsing. The result is that jQuery only sees one slash. If you're creating the selector dynamically, you don't need to create two slashes.

Comment: Ah, that could well explain the behaviour then! +1